# Is it grammatically acceptable to start each options by 'or'?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

I've been using this wording and was wondering if it is grammatically acceptable:

"I wanted, or an apple, or an orange, or even a pineapple, but not a cake!"

I was under the feeling that it showed the exasperation of the speaker better than:

"I wanted an apple, an orange or a pineapple, but not a cake!"

It feels that the frustration is felt only at the end of the sentence in the second option but that the first option shows it from the start.

Comment: There is no *rule* that one form of punctuation expresses frustration more than another form. It's entirely subjective how it's interpreted. For instance, I might say, "I wanted an apple. Or an orange. Or even a pineapple. But not a cake!" Breaking it up by adding pauses, whether with additional conjunctions or even creating multiple sentences, changes the cadence. But how that changed cadence is interpreted is up to each reader. You're talking about style, not grammar.

Comment: @JasonBassford: You have missed the point, which is whether the first item in a list can be preceded by 'or', as it can in Hungarian, for example. The OP gives an example (which is clearly ungrammatical in English).

Comment: @TonyK The existing answers already address the ungrammatical nature of the first *or*. I was commenting on if punctuation can convey frustration.

Comment: @JasonBassford I know that style is quite personal. My reasons for mentioning style in my question was just to give some background as to why I wanted to verify if the first example was grammatically valid or not... and if not, why it wasn't. To sum it up, I wanted to use the first example given, thinking that it had an interesting sound to it but wanted to confirm its grammatical validity, not its style.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use *or* before the first item in a list; it has to be *either X or X*. I don't think there is any difference as to the level of 'exasperation' shown.

Comment: Hi Kate. If I would be writing, I would also avoid the first "or". Do you know what grammatical problem it creates? I tend to use that format to put weight on each option and I was wondering if it was just bad style or an actual grammatical issue.

Comment: In modern English we never say 'or A or B' (though this construction was sometimes used in the past). It has to be 'A or B' or 'either A or B'.

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence is not correct in any situation. "Or" is used to link options, not to begin each option.  The first "or" should be removed.

- *I wanted <s>, or</s> an apple, or an orange, or even a pineapple, but not a cake!"*

#### Annoyed people use fewer words, not more

If your intention is to express exasperation, then you could do the opposite of what you have done in your question: instead of duplicating "or", you would omit wherever possible, like this:

1. *I wanted an apple, an orange, or even a pineapple, but not a cake!*
2. *I wanted an apple, an orange -- even a pineapple! -- but not a cake!*

Removing the "or" before "an orange" also makes the sentence flow more quickly, which suggests the writer (or speaker) is speaking in a hurry, as someone who is annoyed would do.

Sentence 1 remains quite neutral, but Sentence 2 is far more annoyed: Here, the dashes around the "pineapple" part indicate an interruption to the train of thought in the sentence, in this case to introduce the unlikely option of a pineapple being an acceptable option (the implication being that the writer doesn't like pineapples). This use of an interruption is a rhetorical device that suggests that the writer is so annoyed that they are not even taking time to gather their thoughts, and just writing what comes to mind.

You might ask how number 2 reads as a list of alternatives if the word "or" isn't present?  The reason is because the sentence ends with " not *(single option)*". The "not" alternative being singular makes it clear that the preceding list of options were alternatives.  This only works well because the sentence was interrupted by "even a pineapple!". Without the interruption, you would need one "or", and you would have to place it before the last option; with the interruption, the interruption itself suggests an alternative.

I would not use this construction (with the interruption) in formal writing, unless it was to make a point (for example, in a political speech or a debate), but it works well in speech.

Comment: Hi Kris. I understand what you are saying but I was just wondering where was the grammatical problem here. Multiple articles seem to say that starting a sentence with a conjunction was actually not a problem and that multiple "or"s could be used too. In my examples, I was picturing someone being angry, then thinking of examples while being upset (before starting the first "or"), then putting weight on each cited option (showing some puzzlement as to why he received a cake) to finally finish with a strong voice with "but not a cake!".

Comment: The grammatical problem is that "wanted" in this sentence can only be understood as a transitive verb, and so the complete clause, in the present tense, would have been "*I want (object)*".  This is the most common English sentence-type: Subject,Verb,Object.  So once you say (or write) "I wanted", you've given the Subject (I) and the Verb (wanted) so the listener (or reader) is expecting an noun clause to follow it to describe the Object.  But "Or" is not a noun clause, it's a conjunction that joins such clauses together.

Comment: @Dan, you seem to be resisting, but please believe us: you can never never never start a list with 'or' in English. It is not really a question of logic; it's just that no native English speaker would ever do it.

Comment: Thank you, Kris, for the precisions brought in your comment. I was actually wondering about the impact of a conjunction present between the predicate and the arguments. I was wondering if the verb would be indeed missing its argument in the presence of that first "or". We usually use the term "sentence fragment" for  incomplete subect-verb pairs. Can we use the same expression for a transitive verb missing its object? Do you want to add your comment to your main answer for me to mark it as "approved answer"? thx

Comment: @TonyK I am sorry if you felt my comments were discrediting your answers. I just wanted to have the grammatical reason for the invalidity of the form proposed in my question. I thought "grammatically acceptable" was precise enough, but I really wanted the grammatical reasons for the first example to be wrong. I would never write this in an essay or article unless it would be quoted. I'm not trying to pick a fight here ;).

Comment: @Dan  Your sentence is not an example of a sentence fragment, though. Unlike a fragment, your example does contain all the necessary components of a complete sentence, and in the right order. However, by inserting that superfluous "or" at the start of your list of options, you've broken a syntax rule of English, and it's this that prevents the proper parsing of the sentence.

Comment: @KrisW It's true that it is not used to join clauses, but only nouns and thus wouldn't affect the integrity of the sentence. When you refer to a "syntax rule", are you talking about the way that 'or' should be used or a general rule?